# Stack elements from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

I am working on a notification system and I want my notifications to start at the bottom right corner and then stack up to the top right corner. How do I do that? Like how do I force it to start at the bottom of the screen?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/2TdCx/

Current CSS:

```
#notifications {
width: 280px;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
float: right;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
height: 100%;
top: 40px;
margin-right: 3.5px;
}

.notification {
font-size: 12px;
width: 270px;
min-height: 20px;
background: #000;
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 6px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 2.5px;
padding-bottom: 2.5px;
margin-top: 10px;
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: looks like you have it minus the position:fixed;

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2TdCx/1/?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think of is using CSS3 [`rotate transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#rotate) to *vertically flip* the container and the items themselves.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/2TdCx/5/)

```
#notifications, .notification {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

- P.S - Notice that this CSS property has some [browser support issues](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Answer (score 3):

This is easily done with `flexbox`, however the support for `flexbox` [isn't very good](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), so unless you're ready to ditch IE8 and IE9 you may need to look for another method.

**Here's how it's done:**

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.child {
  /* whatever */
}
```

And that's all there is to it. Simple, huh? Well there's a [whole lot more that's great about flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) so there's that to look forward to.

Here's an example of this with some basic styling: http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/Gnbfk